# moment : Getting error when formatting date using user language

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am getting this error when i tried to get a display for my date depending user lang using Moment JS library :

```
format.replace is not a function
```

Here is the code :

```
var localeData = moment.localeData();

switch (navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage) {
    case 'fr':
        localeData = moment.localeData('fr');
        break;
}

localeData.longDateFormat('LL');

var dateToDisplay = moment(1459035326000, "x").format(localeData);
```

Comment: I don't see `format.replace` in that code. where is the error in that code?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Error is thrown on last line and included into moment js library. I have certainly a mistake in my call somewhere

Comment: Have a look at my answer to your other question. I think it will clear up a lot of what is going on with this. This is not how you should be changing locale.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
var format = localeData.longDateFormat('LL');
var dateToDisplay = moment(1410715640579).format(format);
```

because `longDateFormat()` returns a string containing the date format like `'MMMM D, YYYY'` and you should pass this string to the `format()` function.